# Magento2 : Category not saving

Tags: magento2, category

I have tried to save the category and getting below error in Magento2 admin.

> Error: `URL key for specified store already exists`

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: It may be possible when its already assign **URL KEY** to object.
You can check/find in **rewrite** table in database.

Comment: As a temporary solution assign different url key

Answer (score 0):

While Creating category go to Search Engine Optimization Tab & Then Remove the URL KEY Value & Then Try to save Category then it will work

Comment: I removed the URL KEY Value and tried to save but not working

Comment: Do Reindexing & Clear Cache Once then try

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting the unused product's rewrites in URL rewrite table and check

   delete from url_rewrite where entity_type='product' and entity_id NOT IN (Select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
2. Make Sure you are NOT using same name for 2 category

   ```
   Magento generates URL key from the name, if we try to add category with existing name it will show error
   ```

Hope it works!